# Simlifying [(k+1)! - 1] + (k+1)((k + 1)!)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial

I'm afraid I've gotten a bit rusty on Math since I was last in university. I was looking at a problem in my text book that simplified

```
[(k+1)! - 1] + (k+1)((k + 1)!) down to (k+2)!-1
```

I couldn't quite understand how this was done. Would anyone care to explain how this would work step by step? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collect the two terms involving $(k+1)!$:

$$\begin{align*}
\Big(\color{blue}{(k+1)!}\color{red}{-1}\Big)+(k+1)(k+1)!&=\color{blue}{(k+1)!}+(k+1)(k+1)!\color{red}{-1}\\
&=(k+1)!\Big(1+(k+1)\Big)-1\\
&=(k+1)!(k+2)-1\\
&=(k+2)!-1\;,
\end{align*}$$

since

$$(k+2)!=(k+2)\Big((k+1)(k)\ldots(2)(1)\Big)=(k+2)(k+1)!\;.$$

Answer (score 2):

$(k+1)! - 1 + (k+1)(k + 1)!$

$=(k+1)!-1+k(k+1)!+(k+1)!$

$=(k+1)!-1+(k+2)!+(k+1)!$

$=(k+2)!-1$

Answer (score 0):

(k+1)! are common factors of the first and last terms
[image]

Comment: You should learn $\latex$

Comment: Can I draw those arrows using latex?

Comment: @Mufasa Point taken, but I think the benefits of a well-typed $\tex$ answer contribute more than the arrows. You could use this; $[(k+1)!+(k+1)(k+1)!] -1=(k+1)![1+k+1]-1=(k+1)![k+2]-1$

Comment: Sorry - wasn't trying to be sarcastic but just curious as to whether or not latex has such a facility?

Comment: @Mufasa Some packages usually allow you to draw arrows, although I'm not sure any of them is supported on the MSE platform.

Comment: Thanks guys - I'll make a concerted effort to learn latex. I can see it definetely has its advantages over hand-drawn images.